# @media only screen and (min-width:769px) doesn't work

Tags: css

I can not understand why does not work property css

```
@media only screen and (min-width:974px) {
    #bg_top {
        background:url(../img/bg_top.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    }
    #left_column {
        float:left;
        width:22.4%;
    }
}
```

Everything written is true, but on the site, this property does not work. I ask you to explain what my mistake.

Comment: "Does not work" isn't specific enough. What should it do?

Comment: Tag <div id="left_column"></div> to set a style that I wrote on top

Comment: On screen 1900px this css property is why it is not working

Comment: Please add your code in the comment section to your poste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOM doesn't see your condition, only the last (

```
@media only screen and (min-width:973px) and (min-width:973px)
```

)

In the row upside, you used the wrong syntax. 
The correct syntax comment in css is:

```
/* ÐœÐ¾Ð±Ð¸Ð»ÑŒÐ½Ð°Ñ Ð²ÐµÑ€ÑÑ‚ÐºÐ° */
```

Perhaps the wrong code invalidate your condition. Try the correct syntax